# How can I organise kerberos keytabs and ccaches?

Tags: postgresql, kerberos

I have a bit of a problem understanding how to design a system that communicates using the kerberos protocol. Let's imagine - I have an application instance that has a large number of plugins that need to communicate with different services. For example, one plugin is responsible for working with postgres, another plugin is responsible for working with "windows AD". But I need these plugins not to have access to each other's services. I.e. postgres plugin should not be able to go to windows ad service and vice versa. Or if I have multiple instances of the postgres plugin running, there should be different service accesses for each of them.
What is the actual question - how do I store keytabs and/or ccaches so that each service has its own, restricted accesses from the others. Let's say the pgx library requires that there already be a TGT (ccache) on connection to the system, it can only be changed in the environment variable of the whole application. But what should I do if I need to create another connection in the same application, but with a different TGT? It would be nice if the pgx library could take the keytab and generate the TGT automatically with every connection, but unfortunately it doesn't know how to do this.
I just don't understand, how I could organize multiple connections from my application, taking into account that every plugin must have different accesses, and considering that several plugins can connect either to the same service, or to different ones

Comment: Your question is much too broad for SO.. You need to confine questions to a single programming issue, not a generalized design. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tour), see the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section and review [ask]. Ask another question when you have specific issues. Voting to close.

Comment: Short answer: use one TGT for your bizarre multi-faceted app, multiple service tickets to access multiple services, and stop trying to isolate credentials that are used by the _same_ process -- threads are not strictly isolated from each other anyway.